# Angular 2 how to display a backslash in template

Tags: angular, special-characters

I am trying to display a backslash `\` in the component template but it is not get rendered.

```
//example :
template `
           <div>{{'\'}}{{content}}</div>
         `
where content is an @Input string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an inline template, then you need to escape `\` as `\\` like in any other string.

```
 <div>{{'\\'}}{{content}}</div>
```

or

```
<div>\\{{content}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the html code

```
&bsol;
```